# Useful to split table with many columns?

Tags: entity-framework

Let's say I have a thing called 'Case'. A Case has properties, like:
ID
DatePlanned
Deadline
Title
Description
FirstSignatory
SecondSignatory
Priority
Cause
Type
...

Some of these properties can be grouped and be talked about as 'Regulation'. This means there's actually a one-to-one relation between Case and Regulation.

Does it make sense to split the above table into two objects in EF?
Most properties are mandatory, and we probably would almost never load 'Case' without the 'Regulation' properties.

I think it doesn't make sense to break this table into two tables, but on the other hand, it makes it easier to see what's going on in the diagram for example.

Answer (score 1):

Table splitting is useful feature which will enable you to devide table into 1:1 related entities where you can load only main entity and lazy load relations. But you mentioned this:

> Most properties are mandatory, and we
>   probably would almost never load
>   'Case' without the 'Regulation'
>   properties.

In case when you will always load all properties you can define single entity and [complex types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738472.aspx) for its properties.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you need [Table Splitting](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2008/12/05/table-splitting-mapping-multiple-entity-types-to-the-same-table.aspx).
Actually there is no problem in this case, of course if you don't have a large number of such tables (in this case these entities will enlarge the model).